# Formula Help - Pricing/ROI Calculator

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am trying to figure out the proper formula for Sheets and am running in to a brick wall.

I am building a calculator to requires one cell for me to enter monthly subscription cost that can be manually changed based on the package the customer chooses (I3).

The volume of orders in revenue (D13) changes the micro fee per transaction by percentage. This number is auto populated based on other formulas.

I would like the micro fee percentage to change based on the subscription fee as well as the revenue.  So, when you type in $99 or $139 it will pull the revenue and base the micro transaction fee on the IFS.

Here is my formula that I am erroring out on.  By no means am I a sheets wizard, so I hope my broken formula give a good idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.  Any help with fixing this formula would be greatly appreciated as I have tried 20 different videos and changes but can't seem to get it to work.  Ty in advance.

=IFS(I3=$99,D13>10000,5.4%,D13<= 10000,2.9%,(I3=$139,D13>15000,5.4%,D13<= 15000,2.9%))

Comment: Your formula, even if incorrect, absolutely does not take into account calculation differences due to different packages, that is, whatever value `I3` has, the result does not change ... it changes only as the amounts of cell `D13` vary.
Write in English what the results should be.

Comment: Thanks Daniele,

Comment: Thanks Daniele,
As simple as I can explain

Package A - $99 + 2.9% Transaction Fee Up to $10,000.  Additional above $10K is charged an additional 2.5%.

Package B - $139 + 2.9% Transaction Fee Up to $15,000.  Additional above $15K is charged an additional 2.5%.

I want to be able to fill in the cost of $99 or $139 in a cell and have a different cell populate with the correct percentage that will be charged based on the revenue clip levels.

Hope that clarifies a bit.

Comment: Look at the [attached picture](https://prnt.sc/JEY8BiR7Wbqc)
I believe it is convenient that you attach a link to a test file with the results you would like to obtain.

Comment: ... unless that + 2.9% and + 5.4% go to increase the cost of the 2 types of pachages

Comment: I began reading this post earlier but skipped over it because it did not contain a link to a spreadsheet with realistic data and expected result. Keep in mind that we can't see what you are seeing. We don't know your spreadsheet, layout, locale, data, data types or big-picture goal. So trying to *imagine* all of that is not efficient and highly prone to error. I do suggest, along with Daniele, that you share a link to a spreadsheet that fully and clearly illustrates your goal.

Comment: Hi, welcome to WebApps. When you are adding information about the core issues of your question, would you please edit your question to include that data. For example,  "Package A - $99 + " - all that information needs to be in the question too so that people reading your question can see ALL of the relevant information.